# SObject type does not allow locking rows

Tags: apex, soql, query, locking

I am trying to update a group of records satisfying certain conditions it was giving me Error which says:-

> UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record
>   or 10 records

so I tried to use `FOR UPDATE` clause for this query but now it is giving me this error:-

> SObject type does not allow locking rows.

Here is the query I am using:

```
Select Id from user where lmscons__Cornerstone_ID__c != NULL AND 
lmscons__CFS_Status__c = 'Active' AND Checked_Today__c = true LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE
```

Comment: The error usually occurs when multiple users are trying to update the same record, or there might be some triggers or @future jobs updating the record. Please share your query. Do you use `FOR UPDATE` in your query?

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to lock the user records. Rest most of the objects allow this, but not user may be. I haven't been able to find a documentation on this.

Comment: @MohitArora If I execute this query in start method of the batch class will I get an exclusive access to the records?

Comment: Well that would be a hit and trial.

Comment: This is very interesting. I would expect some property in SObjectType.describe like "Lockable" to understand which SObject types are lockable but there is none

Comment: As far as I understand this is specific behavior for User Object.

Answer (score 3):

This is specific behavior for `User` object. For any other standard or custom object, `FOR UPDATE` Keyword is working while for `User` it is not.

This might be drawback of Salesforce platform that there is no list of object types available for [`FOR UPDATE` keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm).

I suggest to [open an idea to elaborate documentation](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E8oXQAS) to provide list of object types which support `FOR UPDATE` keyword. I have just opened a one, so vote for it to persuade Salesforce implement this.

Also I would expect some property in SObjectType Describe like "Lockable" to understand if this object type supports `FOR UPDATE` keyword or not.